# Want to hang-up from my Twilio Java client

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a Java application which uses the Twilio API to connect to Twilio and pass it a number in my org. to call. Twilio calls the number, I play it a message from my phone system and then I want my Java program to read Twilio's transcription of that message.

The problem I have is that Twilio doesn't know when to hang-up! I can't tell it to hang-up after the `<record>` verb as it does a submit at that point, so I want to do a `Thread.sleep(20 * 1000)` in my Java and then end the call from the Java? Possible? I can't see how to do it via the API. I've tried:

```
Call.updater(phoneHome.getSid()).setStatus(UpdateStatus.COMPLETED);
```

and:

```
Call.deleter(phoneHome.getSid()).delete();
```

but to no avail!

Also open to other ways of achieving same end in the TwiML, etc. Had a look at the `<gather>` and `<redirect>` but not sure I could make that work if the recording is playing, that only seems to work if nothing is played, i.e. silence from the called-party (my org.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I didn't want to have to do is send the GET request from the `<record>` verb anywhere as that would entail opening up a firewall gap into my organization, not an easy process.

So, I sent a get request to another TwiML document on Twilio which has a `<Hangup/>` verb in it. The sent recording never leaves Twilio, but that's Ok. I just wanted the call to end and the `maxLength="20"` on the `<record>` verb dictates when it ends. HTH.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist from Twilio, this sounds like you have solved your issue for now. But do let me know if there's anything else I can help with.